# PHP DOMDocument : loop through all elements with text in an html string

Tags: php, laravel

I made a php method which takes an html string and loops through all "p" paragraph elements and translates them, **now I want to improve my method to loop through all elements with text inside! So h2, span, a elements.**

Can you help me?

My PHP method

```
$htmlString = 
        '<section>
        <h2>Ámbito de aplicación</h2>
        <p>
            Estas condiciones generales constituyen las condiciones de uso
            junto con las normas comunitarias, disponibles en
            http://add.com/community-rules y las posibles condiciones
            complementarias pactadas entre el usuario!.
        </p>
    </section>';
        

        
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

        foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) 
        {
            //$nodeValue
            $nodeValue = $pnode->nodeValue;

            $translated = $this->translate($nodeValue)

            $newNode = $dom->createElement("p", $translated );

            $pnode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $pnode);
        }
        $dom->saveHTML($dom);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: loop through irrespective whether its a child or sibling element right?

Comment: yes, I want to grab all elements with text inside and replace them with their translated values

Comment: It would probably make more sense if you looped over all nodes to begin with, and then worked only on those that are text nodes. Not necessary to replace the `p` node (or any other) itself, when you can just replace the text node instead.